# kineticjs line points array contentes

Tags: line, kineticjs, points

what are the interpretation values in the"" points assignment. all I want is a "plane jane" line where I can manipulate the length and width.  Any help will greatly appreciated.

var line = new Kinetic.Line({
  x: 100,
  y: 50,
  points: [73, 70, 340, 23, 450, 60, 500, 20],
  stroke: 'red',
  tension: 1
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The points array is a series of x,y coordinates:

```
// [73, 70, 340, 23, 450, 60, 500, 20],

{x:73,y:70},
{x:340,y:23},
{x:450,y:60},
{x:500,y:20}
```

This is your "plain jane" line:

```
// draw a black line from 25,25 to 100,50 and width of 5

var line = new Kinetic.Line({
    points:[25,25, 100,50],
    y:100,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 5
});
```